# How do I adapt an existing licence from a forked project giving all due credit to the original author?

Tags: github, licensing, fork

I intend to fork a github project that contains the following licence:

```
Copyright (c) 2013 Michel Nemnom

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this  software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies
of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do
so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

This existing project maps sqlalchemy objects to the DataTables jQuery plugin.  I am adapting this project to map to the jTable plug in.

Is it sufficient to put the following in the licence text?  Edit: I intend to include the full licence text.  I want to replace the original copyright notice with the two lines below.

```
Copyright (c) 2013 Chris Strutton
Portions Copyright (c) 2013 Michel Nemnom

Permission is hereby granted, ... (the balance of the existing licence text)
```

I have also put a link back to the original git repo indicating where I forked it from.

Comment: Just a side note:  I did find similar questions however, there was either no accepted answer or involved different enough circumstances that I felt I needed clarification.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: Funny, how can any of us release a single line of code without thinking about this issue.  IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no. The licenses says (my own highlights):

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this  software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, **subject to
>   the following conditions**:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice **shall be
>   included** in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So I would mean that you have to include it all. To be on the safe side, you could ask Michel Nemnon.

**EDIT** (as answer to comment)

I think the best/correct way is to keep the original copyright notice exactly as stated, and then include your own notice on the top. For example:

```
Copyright (c) 2013 Chris Strutton
<Your own copyright notice here, 
perhaps with link to original project and description of own contributions>


Copyright (c) 2013 Michel Nemnom

Permission is hereby granted, ... (the balance of the existing licence text)
```

Comment: See the above edit.  I was planning to include the entire licence text, modifying the original copyright notice to read as above (then include the complete licence text as in the original).